# Kaldi for Gender identification

Tags: identification

Im looking for a software/library that can identify the gender of an speaker. If a have a audio file i want the software to detect what gender has spoken and for how long. Do you know if it is possible with Kaldi http://kaldi-asr.org/

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This script is a good start in the kaldi examples for gender identification: https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/blob/master/egs/sre08/v1/sid/gender_id.sh

You need to build your identifier based on your dataset, it will create UBM  model for the whole dataset, for women, for men. (A Universal Background Model is upposed to model the "world"). 
Finally, make predictions for the provided utterances.